# Why can my Android app no longer receive incoming SMSs?

Tags: android

I'm using SMS to verify the phone number of my user’s. My application is set to receive incoming SMSs and has been working. Now, it is running on a device that does have Telephony and the SMS is being received by the device, but I'm getting reports that my app is no longer successfully receiving and processing the SMS. Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

There are situations that applications can't receive the incoming SMSs. If your app isn't running in the primary user profile then it may not be able to receive SMSs. This can happen when you are running in a secondary user profile, a restricted profile or a managed profile (aka Android for Work).

If you are using the phone number as the user's primary identification then you probably don't want to allow access in restricted profiles or secondary user profiles anyway, so check the `RestrictionsManager` for `UserManager.DISALLOW_SMS` as it will be set to disallowed in these circumstances.

```
UserManager um = (UserManager) getSystemService(Context.USER_SERVICE);
Bundle restrictions = um.getUserRestrictions();
boolean disallowSMS = restrictions.getBoolean(UserManager.DISALLOW_SMS, false);
```

However, for managed profiles, where the user has a personal and a managed (work) profile on their device, the SMS is routed to the personal profile. So if your app is in the managed profile it won't receive the SMS. In this case you probably do want to allow access as it is still being used by the the primary user of the device. Having a fallback method to allow them to read a code from the SMS and enter it manually, or using a phone call service can be valid alternatives.